# Ehcache configuration with wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, wildfly, ehcache

Trying to implement ehcache using ehcache.xml in wildfly10

Added ehcache.jar file as a module and added dependencies as mentioned below:

```
   <resources>
       <resource-root path="ehcache-1.2.2.jar"/> 
   </resources>

   <dependencies>
       <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
       <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
       <module name="javax.xml.parsers"/> 
   </dependencies>


</module>
```

I am getting following error when I try to run server war file.

> Error configuring from d:\ehcache.xml. Initial cause was Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was __redirected.__SAXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

Any lead will be helpful.

StackTrace:

- net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: Error configuring from
  d:\ehcache\ehcache.xml. Initial cause was Error configuring from
  input stream. Initial cause was __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
  cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory
  net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:80)
  net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.parseConfiguration(CacheManager.java:752)
  net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:386)
  net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.(CacheManager.java:295)
  MySqlTest.ehcache(MySqlTest.java:93)
  MySqlTest.processRequest(MySqlTest.java:77)
  MySqlTest.doGet(MySqlTest.java:224)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
  javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
  org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
  io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
  io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
  io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
  io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
  io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
  io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: You need to make sure the path is in modules/javax/api/main/module.xml
and then just add <module name="javax.api"/> as a dependency to your module.

Comment: Hi, thanx for your comment, 

I tried that, but in vain, I will try it once again.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to use Ehcache 1. This version is really really really old. You should at least upgrade to Ehcache 2. The latest is Ehcache 3. It is highly possible that Ehcache 1 isn't compatible with your current Java version and the wildfly dependencies.

Comment: Moved to ehcache 2.9.0 and it works with java project.  When, I run the same code in a Servlet with Wildfly 10, it gives the following error:

Error configuring from d:\ehcache.xml. Initial cause was Error configuring from input stream. Initial cause was __redirected.__SAXParserFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory

Should I just move to the latest EhCache 3.x??

Comment: Without a full stack trace, it is hard to tell. Of course, 3 is the best :-) By my current guess is that you have classpath issues. Too many SAX dependencies at different levels. To side step the issue, you can use Ehcache 3 Java configuration (instead of XML).

Comment: Yes, Thanx for your post. upgrading my project from older jboss to new jboss. So, wanted to deploy my project  in minimal efforts. But it seems that I will have to put in more efforts.. :)

Stacktrace added to the main question.  Will try to resolve classpath issues first and then move to ehcache 3.x, if in vain.

Comment: Ok. SAXParserFactory is included in the JDK. Wildfly my overload it but that shouldn't matter. Try removing anything implementing it from your classpath (or war). Xerces for instance.

Comment: Finally Done via XML.

Wildfly gave an exception no class def found : org.xml.sax.parsers.  So, I added that module as dependency.  But, it didn't work.

Then I added javax.api as a dependency, instead of org.xml.sax.  It worked.

Finally, Widlfly 10, Ehcach 3.3.1 through XML configuration. Success.

Thanks all for your time.

Comment: Just for everybody's knowledge, ehcache 1.x also worked.

Answer (score 1):

It worked with EhCache 3.3.1

1. Put ehcache-3.3.1.jar file in wildfly10_HOME\modules\system\layers\base\org\ehcache\main
2. Edit module.xml in the above folder as below
3. Code:

String cacheName = "basicCacheNamit";

```
try (CacheManager cacheManager = newCacheManagerBuilder()
  .withCache(cacheName,
    newCacheConfigurationBuilder(Long.class, String.class, heap(100).offheap(1, MB)))
  .build(true)) {
  Cache<Long, String> basicCache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName, Long.class, String.class);


  basicCache.put(1L, "da one!");
  String value = basicCache.get(1L);
```